# EditText not showing the hint or the outline box until focused

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, android-edittext, android-textinputlayout

I saw that there are numerous threads raised on this topic but none of them seems to solve my issue.

I have an EditText inside of InputLayout and it shows blank until focused.

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"

            >
            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/etInput"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:hint="Name"/>
```

Android version 12[image]

Comment: Is this perhaps a theme issue, where the hint is really there, but it is rendered in white on a white background?

Comment: Add your hint in TextInputLayout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout                   
                style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="Name"
                app:hintTextColor="@color/black"
                app:boxStrokeColor="@color/black"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                app:boxStrokeWidth="2dp"
                android:textColorHint="@color/black"
                >

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/etInput"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"                      
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
/>
</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Comment: can you try this bro it should work